# How to load property file which is present in outside webapps folder Spring4.0?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to load the property file

Below is the line of code I have in spring.xml of 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet'

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/var/opt/vmware/comeproperties/application.properties" />
```

I am always getting FileNotFoundException always.

What I realized is that th application is always trying to look from the classpath after appending additiona '/'.

Could you please let me know what is the best way to load the property file which is present outside the webapps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "file:" to the beginning of your path like:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${user.home}/folder/test/app.properties" />
```